# Do we lose objc_retain()/objc_release() optimization for ARC if we override retain/release methods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, clang

Edited: Some of you think *ASDealloc2MainObject* from *AsyncDisplayKit* doesn't really override retain/release. I modified the source code behind *ASDealloc2MainObject* ([line 405-428 of *_AS-objc-internal.h*](https://github.com/facebook/AsyncDisplayKit/blob/master/AsyncDisplayKit/Private/_AS-objc-internal.h#L405)), added a printf() inside the overridden release method and did a few test runs on my iPhone. The log was printed as expected. My test code (including a new class that inherits from *ASDealloc2MainObject*) was compiled with ARC enabled.

---

I used to believe that overriding retain/release methods cannot be done under ARC. Turns out I was wrong. Such a technique involves a base class compiled under MRC and its subclasses compiled under ARC.

One good example is the Facebook [AsyncDisplayKit](https://github.com/facebook/AsyncDisplayKit). Lots of classes from the Facebook AsyncDisplayKit framework inherit from a base class called ASDealloc2MainObject. ASDealloc2MainObject is a class that compiles under MRC and overrides NSObject's retain/release methods. In the meantime, subclasses of ASDealloc2MainObject compiles and runs under ARC.

I have two questions:

1. [Quite a few blog posts](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html) on the internet say that when ARC is inserting memory management code during compile time, it will insert low level C functions such as objc_retain() and objc_release() rather than their Obj-C equivalents [NSOject retain] and [NSObject release]. ARC does this because low level C functions could provide extra optimization, such as eliminating costly Obj-C message sending and canceling adjacent autorelease and retain calls. My question here is, if we use the MRC/ARC overriding technique, do we lose such optimization?
2. My second question is in some way related to my first question. What's the runtime behavior of objc_retain()/objc_release() if the target object's base class has overridden its retain/release methods? My guess is that these C functions are able to figure out the situation here. Instead of performing their regular optimizations (such as eliminating sending retain/release messages), they would in fact revert to the old way and actually sends out retain/release messages.

Comment: you can't override retain/release function in ARC, and objc_retain() and objc_release() is only auto insert in ARC. If you not use ARC not objc_retain() and objc_release() auto insert in your code and you control memory with retain/release method you did override

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the documentation:

> You would implement [the retain] method only if you were defining your own reference-counting scheme. Such implementations must return self and should not invoke the inherited method by sending a retain message to super.

Are you implementing your own memory management system? No? Then do not override retain or release.

Apple also advises against using reference counting for all Objective-C code. You are supposed to be using ARC.

`ASDealloc2MainObject` does not override retain or release. Old versions did but FaceBook realised that was a terrible idea and have updated their code to use ARC.

As for how exactly ARC behaves, the answer is "it depends". There are many different ways it can behave. Go read the compiler source code if you really want to know how it works.

That blog post you linked to is ancient and should not be trusted at all. Apple makes breaking changes to the compiler every 12 months and that means they've done so 3 times since the blog post was written. Since memory management is a performance bottleneck, that's where they make the most changes each year.

Sending a "retain" or "release" message to an object is outrageously slow. ARC and the Objective-C runtime both try to avoid sending messages as much as possible. One of the reasons the Swift language was created was to eliminate sending messages altogether. objc_retain() and objc_release() exist to avoid sending retain and release to an object. There might be situations where they do so but you can't rely on it.

Comment: Please see my edited answer. I did some tests and I do think the overridden retain/release methods of my ARC-enabled subclasses of ASDealloc2MainObject indeed get called in an ARC-enabled scope. I was running the test based on the AsyncDisplayKit code freshly cloned from GitHub. They are the newest version.

Comment: @DiWu I'm guessing the compiler detects that you've overridden retain/release and decides to write different code to the binary. Apple has said that objc_retain()/release were created 3 years ago specifically because -retain and -release are too slow. How can they be faster than retain/release if they call retain/release? Also, when performance testing my code I used to see retain/release all the time as a performance bottleneck. These days I never see retain or objc_retain. Under Normal operation ARC does not call retain or release. You're triggering a compatibility mode in the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you write some code and try it. I'd expect that retain/release are not actually called from ARC code, because it uses (faster) function calls. So your overrides won't work when called from ARC. They probably work when called from non-ARC code.

That's to find out what happens. In practice, overriding retain/release in mixed ARC/non-ARC code will probably just get you into trouble.

Comment: Please see my edited answer. I did some tests and I do think the overridden retain/release methods of my ARC-enabled subclasses of ASDealloc2MainObject indeed get called in an ARC-enabled scope.